# Selectively overriding a computed column

Tags: sql-server, sequences

I have a feeling this is a simple yes or no answer but I am going to ask it anyways.

I am using a sequence to populate a given ClientID column in my table. This ClientID however can be persisted across multiple records within the table, each one representing a different version of the record, of which only a single is "Active".

My concern is that the first time I preform a revision on the record, which will "Delete" the record by setting it's Deleted bit, and create a new record in the same table with the new values. The new record will have a new ClientID value given to it where it should have persisted the previous ClientID value.

```
UID ClientID Name        Deleted
20   1        Vendor A    0
21   2        Vendor B    0
```

If I were to add a new record (non-revision), I would expect the following:

```
UID ClientID Name        Deleted
20   1        Vendor A    0
21   2        Vendor B    0
22   3        Vendor C    0
```

But if I were to want to rename (Vendor B) to say ABC Corp, I would want to mark record 22 as deleted and create a new record for "ABC Corp" with a ClientID of 2. (see Below)

```
UID ClientID Name        Deleted
20   1        Vendor A    0
21   2        Vendor B    1
22   3        Vendor C    0
23   2        ABC Corp    0  <-- FK relationships are still in tact.
```

But with the sequence in place, I am expecting to see this instead...

```
UID ClientID Name        Deleted
20   1        Vendor A    0
21   2        Vendor B    1
22   3        Vendor C    0
23   4        ABC Corp    0  <-- Incorrect ClientID (Loss of FK relationship)
```

Can you selectively override a computed column calculation and insert your own value in it's place?

Comment: Really depends on SQL being used to delete and insert the new record.  In My Opinion if this is wrapped in a transaction when you use `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Sequence` to insert the new record you'll get a 4.  If you choose to use the "old"client ID then you could keep it as 2. So it depends on what "VALUE" you assign on the insert. statement.  or is client Id somehow defaulted or have a trigger in place to ALWAYS use the sequence?

Comment: The sequence select is currently set as the default value for the column. So I see that as my first issue.

Comment: ClientID is IDENTITY(1,1), right?

Comment: UID is the identity. ClientID is the result of the sequence select, also effectively acting as Identity so to speak.

Comment: Default values can be overwritten  that's why they are just "DEFAULTED" .  So I don't see why you couldn't simply assign a value of "2" at time of insert to retain client ID 2.  If no value is provided then I would expect the system to automatically assign the sequence next value as it is the default.  But when a user assigns one, then default is overridden and user assigned value wins.  So what's the insert statement look like?  If clientID isn't supplied, that's why you're seeing a 4.

Comment: Thank you, xQbert. The insert does in fact work, however I am posed with a uniqueness issue now, but I believe I have that in hand. 

I have to admit, I posed this question before fully testing it. I got hung up on the logic and assumed the results. Thanks for talking it out with me.